# Kolmogorov's Strong Law and Almost Sure Convergence

Tags: probability, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I would like a help in the following problem

> $(X)_{n \geq 1}$ iid,  $E(X_i) = \xi$ and $Var(X_i) = \sigma_i$.
>
> Show that $\dfrac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}  \rightarrow \xi$ with probability 1, when $\sigma_i = \Delta i^{\alpha}$ and $\sigma_i = i\Delta^i$ and show restrictions for $\Delta$ and $\alpha$.

I tried to solve using Borel-Cantelli Lemma, but won't work. Then, I tried the Kolmogorov Strong Law, but the same problem emerged, the series diverge.
I would appreciate some hints. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify/fix typos?  What is the assumption on $\sigma_i$? (there is a stray $e$ there, and it looks like $\sigma_i$ is defined twice, but differently each time).

Comment: I wrote exactly what is on the problem statement. My attempts of solution were based on the proof of the Kolmogorv Strong Law .

Comment: That is an unusual response. If you do not know how to interpret "$\sigma_i = \Delta i^{\alpha} e \sigma_i = i \Delta^i$", then nobody looking at this question does, either, and I do not know how you can attempt a solution to a problem that is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I took another look at the problem and now, i think i can make myself clear.  The main goal of the problem is prove the almost sure convergence in two cases:  $\sigma_i = \Delta i^{\alpha}$ and $\sigma_i = i \Delta^i$. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant independent, but not identically distributed.

I'm not sure about necessary conditions, but here's a theorem that will allow you to find sufficient conditions on $\Delta$ and $\alpha$ (source: *Probability: A Graduate Course* by Allen Gut):

> **Theorem**: (The Kolmogorov sufficient condition)
>
> Let $\{X_n\}_n$ be independent random variables with mean $\xi$ and finite variance $\sigma_n^2$, and set $S_n = X_1+...+X_n$. If,
>
> $$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_n^2}{n^2} < \infty $$
>
> then the SLLN holds, i.e., $\frac{1}{n}S_n \rightarrow \xi$ with probability $1$.

For example, in the first case, $\sigma_n^2 = \Delta^2 n^{2\alpha}$, we have,

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_n^2}{n^2} = \Delta^2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2-2\alpha}} $$

The above series converges if $\alpha < 1/2$. Try to do something similar for the other case.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for statement is not the best, but your hint really helped. I was able to solve the problem. Once again, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a minor factor of two error in the exponent.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the answer just now.